# Как убрать всплывающее окно при запросе post?

Tags: javascript, php, html

При выполнение запроса на странице, браузер высвечивает предупреждение, текст: **Действие на странице *{url страницы}***

Вот мой код запроса:
`$.post('sec.php',{name1:allText},function(data){alert(data)});`

Вот предупреждение:

[image: Предупреждение на странице]

Подскажите, как я могу убрать это окно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: при заходе на страницу высвечивается окно код уже вписан в странице   как убрать уведомление это в любом браузере так

Answer (score 1):

У меня была эта проблема, как я тогда понял(как нашёл на просторах интернета) эта баг Chrome. Тем не менее есть несколько способов:

1. Подключите к сайту SSL сертификат, в большинстве случаев браузер перестанет ругаться.
2. Используйте для отправки сообщений Ajax запрос(JQuery - Javascript)
3. Используйте "человеческий" домен. У вас специфический домен, браузеры такие не любят.(Соц.сети кстати будут выдавать предупреждение при попытке перейти туда, например из диалога)

P.S в моём случае перестал ругаться при ajax запросах, но в итоге я сменил домен на нормальный, и даже при прямой отправке формы, всё отлично

Comment: а как переделать запрос мой в ajax ????

Comment: @Иван ajax это метод фреймворка JQuery(Написанного на Javascript). Если Вы понимаете о чём я сейчас говорю, то изучить основы ajax, по крайней мере для выполнения запроса у вас займет от силы день. Вот примеры запросов: https://good-code.ru/ajax-zapros/ Внимание крайне не советую что-то учить по примерам, лучше прочитайте документацию, но если вы сильно торопитесь, можете взять что-то от сюда и создать запрос.

Comment: @Иван если же у Вас нет понимания, что я написал выше, увы, боюсь вам придётся подучится ещё, начните с изучения Javascript затем Jquery, потом уже ajax. Либо же всё же купите домен, поискав можно купить его за 99руб/год

Comment: Кстати обратите внимание что Вы тоже используйте `alert()` что как раз и выводит текст который Вы в него передадите на страницу в всплывающем окне. Пожалуйста уточните вопрос, детальнее, возможно я смогу сказать Вам больше